# Panda dataframe groupby and join into columns

Tags: python, pandas

Is there an easy way to do the following: I have a panda dataframe with the following columns: date (by day), company, sales.  I want to create a dataframe with the sales for each company as a column; i.e., the new columns should be: date, company 1 sales, company 2 sales, company 3 sales.  I'd like to name the columns by the name in the company column.

I did: `df.groupby(['company'])` and thought I could an outer join for each element in the group. But this seems unwieldly?  It seems like there should be an easier way to do this?  Thank you!  Any help is greatly appreciated.

An example is:

```
date  |  company  | sales

1/1/2017 | AAA | 100

1/1/2017 | BBB | 200

1/1/2017 | CCC | 300
```

And I want to convert it to:

```
date | AAA | BBB | CCC

1/1/2017 | 100 | 200 | 300
```

Comment: Please post your actual code; however, it sounds like you could accomplish this task using `pivot_table`, like so: `df.pivot_table(index='date', columns='company', values='sales', aggfunc='sum')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***option 1***
`set_index` + `unstack`

```
df.set_index(['date', 'company']).sales.unstack().reset_index()

company      date  AAA  BBB  CCC
0        1/1/2017  100  200  300
```

***option 2***
`pivot`

```
df.pivot('date', 'company', 'sales').reset_index()

company      date  AAA  BBB  CCC
0        1/1/2017  100  200  300
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried to delete the company column from your pivot result (since I don't need it). I couldn't seem to do it with `drop('company', axis=1)`.  How do I get rid of the company column?

Comment: @StanfordWong the 0 is the index. Company is the name of the columns object. You can't get rid of the index. But you can get rid of the name of the columns.  Add the following to either solution: .rename_axis([None], 1)

Comment: Can I ask why do you add the `reset_index()` at the end?  It seems to work fine without it?

Comment: @StanfordWong Usually when I'm answering questions, I try to match what the OP (you) asked for.  What you provided as "I want to convert it to:" Looks like the `date` is a column rather than an index.  So I `reset_index` to make it a column.  Please feel free to leave `reset_index` off.

Comment: Thanks again for the help!